# prove that any language over 1 letter alphabet is regular

Tags: regular-language

I saw such question before, but they all assumed that the language is CFL first and then tried to use pumping lemma or something to prove that it's regular. But I dont have this assumption  in my homework.

Thanks

Comment: Without that assumption, it isn't true. For example the language that contains all strings length a prime number is not regular because it never becomes periodic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you mentioned the main questin was "Is it regular" not "Prove that it's regular". But what about L* ?